# Мультимедиа контент на странице html5

Tags: html5, firefox, аудио, opera

До создания кода мультимедийной части я еще не дошел, но простым тестом увидел, что все не так просто.
Код:

```html
<audio controls>
   
        <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
<br>
<audio controls>
        <source src="2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
<br>
<audio controls>
        <source src="3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
<br>
<audio controls>
        <source src="4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
<br>
<audio controls>
        <source src="5.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
<br>
<audio controls>
        <source src="6.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
<br>
<audio controls>
        <source src="7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
<br>
<audio controls>
        <source src="8.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
<br>
<audio controls>
        <source src="9.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

по разному отображается в опера и ффоксе. Слева ффокс, справа опера.
http://itmages.ru/image/view/4325665/1baba3b2

---

Почему, что именно так отображается и как сделать чтобы мультимедийный контент работал? Ссылки в ответах приветствуются.

---

Дополняю и конкретизирую: Почему в ффоксе все 9 "файлов" отображаются, а в опере только 6? С правами на сервере все в порядке. html код абсолютно одинаковый.

Comment: Ну по идее это стандартный дизайн плеера в браузерах. Если хочешь что бы был свой статический дизайн - нужно сделать свой плеер.

Comment: нееее!!! Я от  том что в ффоксе отображаються все 9 музык, а в опере только 6. Подправлил вопрос.

Comment: ... ;:)) поэтому и нужно четко и правильно формулировать вопросы. ну э-э-э..., чтобы получить ответ.

Comment: А вы ждать не пробовали? Может они не подгрузились просто? И нажмите F12 - ошибок нет? Так же какая версия оперы?

Comment: ааа, может все дело в опере ? Версия 37.0.2178.43 для Линукса, НО может в винде все будет хорошо показывать? По поводу ждать %:;))) что же (и солько) мне ждать от локалхоста??? в линуксе эта опера показывает button слишком мелкие, так что это может быть из-за нее.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, в аналогичной виндовой версии оперы у меня все ок

Comment: На форум им напишите чтоли: http://forums.opera.com/categories/en-opera-for-nix

Comment: Я поставил https://vivaldi.com/ тоже такая самая фигня. Винду еще не запускал (она у меня в виртуале)

Comment: только что проверил в опере в виртуалке в винде - там вообще все 9 не хотят играть. странно все это. а в фф в той же виртуалке все отлично.

Comment: http://itmages.ru/image/view/4356890/3e47bc37